# SQL: Counting the total number of distinct items within a category

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table called Courses with the following data:

```
Field   | Specialisation


science    pathology
arts       film studies
science    neuroscience
arts       english
science    biotechnology
arts       english 
arts       music  
science    biotechnology
```

I want to write an SQL query that shows the total number of distinct specialisations for each field in the table (e.g. for science there would be 3 distinct specialisations and for arts there would be 3 distinct specialisations).

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT Courses.Field,
count(*) AS Count
FROM Courses
GROUP BY Courses.Field;
```

However, this shows the total number of specialisations for each field. How can I get the total number of distinct specialisations for a field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `distinct` inside count

```
SELECT Courses.Field,
count(distinct Specialisation) AS Count
FROM Courses
GROUP BY Courses.Field;
```